# Listview on Popup Window didn't show

Tags: android, jquery, listview, android-listview, popup

I have a listview on popup window, the listview contents obtained from my asynctask, and i have add my contents from my asyctask to **mcodeList**(declared as `ArrayList<String>`). 
i've checked the contents & this is sample **mcodeList** from the Log :

```
Response : > [08-00631 can be found in LAB A, 08-00635 can be found in LAB A]
```

This case when i get contents of **mcodeList**, i don't want that's show direct to the popup window so i don't set listview adapter `onPostExecute`. but i want when i click button popup window, the contents(**mcodeList**) of listview will appear on popup window.

This is my code on popup window :

```
try {
        LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.popup_element);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ListLocationActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_popup, viewGroup);

        pWindow = new PopupWindow();
        pWindow.setContentView(layout);
        pWindow.setWidth(300);
        pWindow.setHeight(200);
        pWindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        Log.d("Response : ", "> "+ mcodeList);
        // Updating parsed JSON data into listview
        ListView lv_popup = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_info);
        lv_popup.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.popup, R.id.mcode, mcodeList));

        btnClose = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                pWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is my popup window layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_element"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background ="#B2FFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView android:id="@+id/list_info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:divider="#B2E0FF"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/btn_close"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Close" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this my list item layout :

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/mcode"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and my first problem is when i click button popup window, the popup is appear, but the listview didn't display. and the second problem is i couldn't close the popupwindow when i click close button, that's like crash on my program, but that's still running.

and i get this warning Log like this :

```
D/AbsListView(17047): Get MotionRecognitionManager
W/System.err(17047): java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err(17047):    at com.example.assetscanner.ListLocationActivity.initiatePopupWindow(ListLocationActivity.java:442)
W/System.err(17047):    at com.example.assetscanner.ListLocationActivity.infoAsset(ListLocationActivity.java:457)
W/System.err(17047):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err(17047):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err(17047):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3655)
W/System.err(17047):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
W/System.err(17047):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17082)
W/System.err(17047):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
W/System.err(17047):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/System.err(17047):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err(17047):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
W/System.err(17047):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err(17047):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err(17047):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
W/System.err(17047):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
W/System.err(17047):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i never found error like this, so please someone can help me.
Thank's before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should change this

```
ListView lv_popup = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_info);
```

With

```
ListView lv_popup = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.list_info);
```

It's becoz your `listview` coming from inflated `layout`

Comment: Oh my god so simple just like that, i'm too careless. but Thanks yaa.